# com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeArgumentsParseException: RNGooglePlaces.openAutocompleteModal got 3 arguments, expected 4

Tags: java, android, react-native

I'm trying to implement Places autocomplete in my react native application.
Previously i was using [react-native-google-places](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-google-places) version 2.5.2 every thing was working fine. Recently i updated to recent version 3.1.2.

```
openSearchModal() {
  RNGooglePlaces.openAutocompleteModal({
    type: 'establishment',
  })
  .then((place, err) => {
    this.setState({ placeObj: place.address, selectedPlace: place.name });
    this.props.callback(place);
    console.log(err);
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error.message)); 
 // error is a Javascript Error object
}
```

The above is the code which will be triggered onButton press.

Every thing works fine in Debug mode.
But when i make the release build i'm getting this error.

```
com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeArgumentsParseException: RNGooglePlaces.openAutocompleteModal got 3 arguments, expected 4
```

Can any one please help me with this.

Comment: In new version you need to call like this          RNGooglePlaces.openAutocompleteModal({ initialQuery: 'vestar', locationRestriction: { latitudeSW: 6.3670553, longitudeSW: 2.7062895, latitudeNE: 6.6967964, longitudeNE: 4.351055 }, country: 'NG', type: 'establishment' }, ['placeID', 'location', 'name', 'address', 'types', 'openingHours', 'plusCode', 'rating', 'userRatingsTotal', 'viewport'] ) .then((place) => { console.log(place); }) .catch(error => console.log(error.message));        for more information you can check               https://github.com/tolu360/react-native-google-places

Comment: Not working. App crashing and getting same error in logcat